# how to list all the DLLs ever loaded by a process even those that were loaded and unloaded before I started monitoring the process

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, process

I have a requirement to find out all the DLLs that a process ever loaded including those that have been unloaded at the time I monitor it.
I know there are many tools for this eg listdlls but they only tell the currently loaded ones - not those that have been unloaded *before* I started monitoring it.

What I'd like is a comprehensive list of DLLs that have been loaded and unloaded upto the point of monitoring.

Comment: Depends.exe has a profile mode. Is this sufficient?

Comment: if dll already unloaded - you not get info about this. it not stored

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/DevNotes/rtlgetunloadeventtrace - Windows stores last 64 unloaded modules internally in NTDLL.DLL. Not sure if it only works for debugged processes though. WinDbg relies on it.

Comment: @xMRi depends.exe only tells the static dependencies not the run-time ones.

Comment: @ImmortaleVBR this *might* turn out to be useful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Information about unloaded modules is not present anywhere in the system. If you need a comprehensive list of all modules ever loaded into your process, you're going to have to monitor the entire lifetime of your process. You can use the [Debugger Engine API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-engine-api-overview) to monitor module load and unload events.

Comment: i wasn't aware the unloaded module names are not stored anywhere. However, @immortale VBR 's comment suggests something that might help me.
Using Debugger Engine API seems to be an overkill as I wanted some readymade tool to give this info.

Comment: @AnuragSSharma: The unsupported `RtlGetUnloadEventTrace` call only returns up to 64 unloaded modules. The same is true when using [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump) passing the [MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minidumpapiset/ne-minidumpapiset-_minidump_type) flag. If you need information about *all* unloaded modules, you're going to have to monitor the entire lifetime of your process.

Answer (score 0):

There is one program I used for similar task, it shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon It shows **all** DLL calls and creates log file. You can filter results by process(application) for example to see how many, which DLL calls were made, for some processes it even shows duration.

Comment: You are describing a tools and its advantages, basically advertising that tool. You do not describe a solution for the question at the top of this page. If you name a tool as solution you need to demonstrate how that tool can be used to solve the problem. Only naming a tool and linking is not considered an answer on StackOverflow and risks being flagged as "not an answer".